# C# GZipStream leaveOpen flag

Tags: c#

```
public GZipStream (System.IO.Stream stream, 
                   System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode mode, 
                   bool leaveOpen);
```

I am trying to understand what does leaveOpen flag does. When this should be set to true or false?

This is the definition: leaveOpen:

> true to leave the stream open after disposing the GZipStream object; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET world several type of `Stream`s wrap another `Stream` to add kind of a new *layer of logic*, like compression/decompression, encryption, etc. In these cases, the stream gets another stream most likely as a constructor argument, like in your example. By convention (I guess..), when a wrapper `Stream` is disposed of, the wrapped `Stream` will get disposed of as well, or get *closed* in other words.

The flag `leaveOpen` means that when the wrapper stream gets closed (disposed), the underlying (wrapped) stream should be left open for further use.

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what it says, when `leaveOpen` is `false` (the default) it will dispose the stream you pass as the first argument when the `GZipStream` instance is disposed.

Depending on how you initialize your streams, you don't want to multiple-dispose objects, like in my usual coding pattern:

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(repositoryPath, file));
using var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
fileStream.CopyTo(gZipStream);
```

Comment: "_you don't want to multiple-dispose objects_" That should not be a concern. From the [documentation of the Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose): "_If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times._"

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, I love "language lawyers". Meanwhile, in the definition of [`ObjectDisposedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=net-6.0) there's an explicit entry for "You've called an object's Dispose or DisposeAsync methods multiple times". There is also a Roslyn analyzer to highlight multiple dipose calls with a warning. And lastly, it's just common sense not to call the same functionality multiple times when you don't need to.

Comment: Well, if you love me, don't forget the flowers and the chocolate. I am not an easy girl, though... <3